# How to create a shortcut for F# compiler (Fsc.exe)?

Tags: windows, f#

I have a stupid question to ask. I have just started learning F#, and I am trying to compile some basics examples (such as HelloWorld.fs).

I created a simple F# file whose path is: `C:\FSharp\HelloWorld.fs`.

In order to compile it, I used the full path of the F# compiler as follows:

`C:\FSharp>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe" HelloWorld.fs`

It worked perfectly.

However, I do not want to keep writing the full path of the complier: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe`. I tried to add it to Windows path,but I keep getting the error `fsc is not recognized as internal or external command`.

How can I create a shortcut word for F# compiler so that I don't have to use the full path everytime I need to compile a program?

Comment: You could add the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0` directory to your path, or if you're using powershell you can create an alias with `set-alias` i.e. `set-alias fsc C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe`.

Comment: I tried to add the C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0 directory to my path variable, but I keep getting the error that fsc is not recognized.

Comment: You'll need to re-open the prompt you're using for it to detect any path changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to create a shortcut for this, you just need to add the folder containing `fsc.exe` to your `PATH` variable.

When you open the command prompt, run this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\"
```

or, if you're using a 64-bit version of Windows:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\"
```

---

The most recent version of fsc.exe can be found in these locations :

- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0"    // as of Aug 2014
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0"    // 2013

Comment: Thank you Jack :) It worked perfectly; I don't know why it didn't work when I tried to add the path manually ( Right Click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings-> ...etc)

Comment: @John : That requires a reboot in order to take effect.

Comment: @ildjarn I think it'll work if you just log out and log back in instead of doing a full reboot.

Comment: @Jack : I suppose that would depend on whether it was added to user variables or system variables. :-]

Answer (score 6):

For those arriving here in 2019 having received F# as a component of Visual Studio 2017. The location of the F# compiler is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsc.exe
```

> Take careful note of the Version Type (`Community` in this case) and adjust yours accordingly.

Comment: For 2019, the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsc.exe`

Answer (score 2):

I tried setting it to my path, but unfortunately it did not work. Tried logging off/restarting etc. I believe it is because of security measures in place on my work computer.

For other people having similar issues, I found that setting the alias not only worked but was more preferable over other methods.

```
set-alias fsi "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\fsi.exe"
set-alias fsc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe"
```

Now the commands don't have the annoying .exe file extension.

Helpful in getting setup was this article on creating persistent aliasing for powershell.
http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/tutorial-powershell-aliases/

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that adding the directory to your `PATH` variable should do the trick (works on my machine!) Note that you may need to restart any opened command line (or, just to make sure, the system) until the change is taken into account if you change the `PATH` variable in system properties.

You could also create a `bat` file with something like:

```
echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe" %*
```

And then make sure the `bat` file is somewhere in your `PATH`. But the `bat` file can have a different name (say `fsharpc.bat`), in case there is some name clash between the standard name `fsc` and something else on your system...